# Constant network connections without delaying other network requests?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, networking, android-asynctask

I am working on a game for Android. Part of it is a custom-coded chat system (Not an IRC).

The chat system uses Android AsyncTask to the method `HttpURLConnection`, making a POST request to a PHP file on my server. This request is generated once per second and works fine when dedicated to chat.

Same logic is applied to all other network requests in the game (such as performing a basic activity) and works fine. However, our development team decided to move the in-game chat to a side pull-out drawer.

Now that the chat is running constantly while the game is open, all other network requests are running very slow. The chat is not being run from the main thread, I created a separate thread to handle this. Each time the thread loops it uses a thread-specific instance of the AsyncTask, but it's still causing the requests to be slow.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong that would cause these delays, or is there a better way to make these requests (considering the chat requests are called once per second)? Please see below for related code.

**Thread used to call chat**

```
public class ChatThread extends Thread {
    public static boolean IsUpdating = true;

    public ChatThread() {

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (IsUpdating) {
                NetworkThread N = new MyAsyncTask();
                final String Result = N.execute().get();
                if (Result.contains("Error Connecting to Server")) {
                    System.out.println("Connection refused, waiting 3 seconds.");
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                }
                Act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        parseChat(Result);
                    }
                });
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error in chat thread: " + e);
        }
    }

    public void parseChat(String Messages) {
        // Parses messages and displays them
    }
}
```

**Structure of AsyncTask**

```
public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public MyAsyncTask() {

    }
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return Global.getMessages("GameUsername", true);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(String page) {

    }
}
```

**`HttpURLConnection` method (called from `Global.getMessages()`)**

```
public static String Request(String UseURL, JSONObject JSON) {
    try {
                String data = "Data=" + URLEncoder.encode(JSON.toString(), "UTF-8");
                URL postURL = new URL(API + UseURL);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) postURL.openConnection();
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
                writer.write(data);
                writer.flush();
                String line;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String retData = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  retData += line;
                }
                writer.close();
                reader.close();
                return consoleBreaks(retData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "Error Connecting to Server: " + e;
    }
}
```

Execution flow:

1. Chat thread starts and runs every second until `IsUpdating` is false.
2. Chat thread creates an instance of AsyncTask and executes the request on an asynchronous request.
3. The AsyncTask makes a request to the server using `HttpURLConnection`.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Please forgive my ignorance, but how would ServerSocket help in this situation? Does it support multiple network threads or runs faster? My server supports pretty much anything, but I was preferring to use PHP as it's my strongest server-sided language and am able to build a lot of custom features using PHP.

Comment: It run faster depending on the internet speed and yes you can use multiple threads on that. You do not need to drop your PHP, this server/client is an add ons but you need to have a server that supports both PHP and Java. You need to have a Java program running in your server to serve as a Chat server while your PHP do what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the solution was not with the local Java, it was with the PHP code. It was trying to process a lot of information (~25000 characters) every second. I restructured the php code and it now runs the requests at ~250ms, which is roughly 1ms per chat line.

**Edit:**

Well, it's been a while since I posted this terrible question but I decided to update this anyways because I ended up using a much smoother method to retrieve messages and hopefully it will give somebody else an idea on how to optimize their stuff. The way the new system works, it only pulls 100 messages the **first time** you open the chat. It saves the most recent ID of the message to a variable and sends that ID to the server when requesting messages. It then only retrieves the messages that have been sent **after** the message ID, then updates the variable locally. It makes things MUCH faster.